# problem in getting up live streaming using Amazon WS

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am following Amazon tutorial to get up a live streaming website up and running from scratch,  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/FeaturedArticles/latest/index.html?FlashMediaLiveEncoder.html

Do I really need to use Route53 service? I am trying to avoid registering a DNS at this point.
Can I use Google app engine - xxxxx.appspot.com domain name and deploy my simple web page on it to display streaming content?

Will appreciate your response. thanks.